# Why is "Asking all remaining processes to terminate" failing during shutdown?

Tags: shutdown

I installed Debian 7. Sometimes when I quick X and type `sudo shutdown -h now`, it says, `Asking all remaining processes to terminate`, then after a few seconds, it prints a long list of processes, then it says that it failed to stop them, then the computer powers off.

- The computer was only recently installed.
- I have had the same distribution on this computer and on other computers, installed in the same manner, but never encountered this before.

Is this problem serious? If so, what could be causing it?

Comment: Any examples you can recall from the list?

Comment: No, the text moves by too fast to see, but the list had at least 20 items. This happens about 1 in 3 times I shutdown. It looked similar to what one sees when one types `top`, but with fewer columns of data.

Comment: Have a look in `/var/log/syslog` (Debian puts a copy of everything it can there, I think) after you reboot to see if there's any record left. It probably isn't a big deal if everything that's truly significant (e.g., stuff you've been directly working on/with) has been closed manually -- but it would be good to know what's up.  *If you can disable ACPI on the box it won't actually turn off,* just the system will shut down, leaving the last thing it printed to the screen visible (you then have to physically turn it off or pull the plug, which is fine at that point).

Answer (score 1):

The init scripts first try to send a TERM signal, so the process ends gracefully. When that fails, the kernel starts to killing them, without waiting that the process finish. You should check which process and maybe end them yourself instead of waiting for the script.